# Configure Windows 10 OpenSSH server User access permissions to only allow Administrators to authenticate?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, openssh

Playing around with the Windows 10 OpenSSH server that is now available on a system that just uses Local accounts and is not setup for a domain and I can't figure out how to control user authentication permisionss.

Out of the box, the Windows 10 OpenSSH server is allowing any User account on the system to login and authenticate using their Windows password.  I want to restrict this so only a specific User account or Users that are in the Administrators Group can login.

When I look at the default sshd_config file created it seems most everything is commented out and I tried adding the following and restarting the SSH service with no effect:

DenyGroups Users

Any tips on how to configure which users/groups can/cannot login after a default installation of the OpenSSH Server?

Comment: Simple way, use key authentication, and only configure a key for the users you want to permit access.  Password authentication isn’t that secure.

Answer (score 0):

The configurations are commented out because the idea is that the default settings are commented out, and then if you want to change the defaults then you uncomment things and change them, or you add your own settings.

Remember you need to restart the sshd service before any configuration changes will take effect.  I was able to give only one account access to the ssh server by adding this to the config file:

```
AllowUsers myuser
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I made sure there was nothing else except the standard config file and I added that line, restarted the OpenSSH service and I was still able to SSH into the system using other non-administrator user credentials.  Did you add something else to explicitly DenyUsers or DenyAdministrators?